# Call Gridster multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable, gridster

I love the drag and drop concept of Gridster, but I have a dynamic set of tiles that changes depending on live updates from Meteor. For example, lets say I have a Tiles array in a User model. When the Tiles array is updated by Meteor, it is hard to ascertain what was added to the Tiles array. Is there a way to call Gridster again on the same container but with new tiles?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly it is you want to accomplish. But you can add and remove items with `add_widget` and `remove_widget`. And you can see what grids were appended by using `serialize_changed`.